# SELECT * BETWEEN AND

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a list of events from a database with MySQL. I'm fairly new to php but usually I can figure stuff out. cant seam to get this to work though..

```
function get_events_within_dates($da,$dd) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * 
        FROM events
        WHERE date 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$da','Y-m-d') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dd','Y-m-d')            
        ORDER BY date ASC";
```

I've used `$da` and `$dd` as date of arrival and date of departure..

I can get it to work fine when I replace the variables with exact dates, tried messing around with `STR_TO_DATE()` and that didn't help either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `%` in the format string. Use `STR_TO_DATE()` as:

```
   STR_TO_DATE('$da','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Full query as below:

```
   $query = "SELECT * 
             FROM events
             WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$da','%Y-%m-%d') 
                        AND STR_TO_DATE('$dd','%Y-%m-%d')            
             ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Comment: oh man i knew it would end up being something stupid too. thanks a lot